# Why my html Video shows different is iPhone?

Tags: html, css, iphone, video

I am creating a html video... my webpage in android phones works correctly with my favorite design. but in iphone shows with higher height.I think it have 100px unwanted padding in top and bottom.
pls help me. thanks alot and excuse me for my bad english.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbK42.jpg)

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="row row-video">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-video">
<video id="myvideo" poster="./images/image.png" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload">
<source src="video.mp4">
</video></div>
```

CSS Code:

```css
/* video body */
.container-video { background-color:#000000;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px;
border-bottom:0px solid green;direction:rtl;}

.row-video {padding:0px;
margin:0px 0px 50px 0px;}

.col-video { padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;}

.col-video video {
display:block;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;
width:100%;
border:0px solid #cf984a;border-radius:0px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #525252, 0px -2px 2px #525252;}
```

Answer (score 0):

could be a display res issue or a default browser styling problem
try including this meta tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and put this in your css:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```